# How to fix ' environment error and package when installing cassandra using conda'

Tags: python, cassandra, anaconda

I'm installing `Cassandra` on my Mac through `anaconda` but i have a problem with the environment :`failed with initial frozen solve`. Retrying with flexible solve. furthermore it gives The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

```
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:

    cassandra-driver -> python=3.6 -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a'] -> ca-certificates
    python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
    Package setuptools conflicts for:
    cassandra-driver -> python=3.6 -> pip -> setuptools
    python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
    Package pip conflicts for:
    python=3.7 -> pip
    cassandra-driver -> python=3.6 -> pip
    Package certifi conflicts for:
    python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
    cassandra-driver -> python=3.6 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
    Package wheel conflicts for:
    cassandra-driver -> python=3.6 -> pip -> wheel
    python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
```